# How to save all responses from a test suite in JMeter in one single file?

Tags: java, rest, jmeter

I am testing a new REST API for my company and I am splitting all of its methods into test suites with different parameter combinations as test cases. I also build negative suites with added assertions.
The suites are huge - they contain more than 100-150 test cases each. I need to be able to save all responses from the suites but in a single file. I found this article which works for me but not entirely http://gerardnico.com/wiki/jmeter/save_response_to_file - here I can add 'Save response to a file' listener but it creates separate files for each response. Basically this is useless, I can check them one by one from the result tree directly in the tool. I searched at multiple articles but I can't seem to find exactly the resolution of my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a JSR223 Listener to your Test Plan (on top level so it will collect the data from all the samplers, see [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for more information)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File("responses.txt") << prev.getResponseDataAsString() + System.getProperty("line.separator")
   ```

When you will run the test next time you will be able to see `responses.txt` file in JMeter's "bin" folder containing all the responses

`prev` is a shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, it provides programmatic access to parent sampler result so you will be able to read or even update certain parts like response code, body, message, overall success, etc. [See Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about using [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) scripting in JMeter test.

Answer (score 1):

I think Simpledatawriter can solve your problem if you use it at test plan level.

- Right click on test plan
- Add "Listener" >> Simple Data Writer.
- Add a file name.
- This will write all responses to a single file. (But it will has record the response code and message)